# RowSelected not being called in UITableView in iOS using Xamarin

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection, xamarin, mouseclick-event

I am trying to do something when a user touches a row in a UITableView.  I am coding for iOS and using Xamarin.

I am assuming that when the user touches a row in the UITableView, and that row is highlighted, that it would mean that the user has just selected a row.  So, I figured it made sense to override the RowSelected method in my UITableViewSource.  For some reason, though, I can't seem to get that method to ever be called.

Here is my complete UITableViewSource implementation:

```
public class DeviceSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public event EventHandler<FoundDevice> DeviceSelected;
    private List<FoundDeviceWithInfo> Devices { get; set; }

    public DeviceSource(List<FoundDeviceWithInfo> devices)
    {
        Devices = new List<FoundDeviceWithInfo>(devices);
    }

    public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
    {
        return Devices.Count;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        base.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath);

        if (DeviceSelected != null)
        {
            DeviceSelected(tableView, Devices[indexPath.Row].FoundDevice);
        }
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell((NSString)indexPath.Row.ToString());

        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new DeviceCell(Devices[indexPath.Row].FoundDevice.IpAddress + ":" + Devices[indexPath.Row].FoundDevice.PortNumber,
                              Devices[indexPath.Row].FoundDevice.DeviceName,
                              Devices[indexPath.Row].DeviceCommonInfo != null ? Devices[indexPath.Row].DeviceCommonInfo.Position.AutoGEOTag.Lat : string.Empty,
                              Devices[indexPath.Row].DeviceCommonInfo != null ? Devices[indexPath.Row].DeviceCommonInfo.Position.AutoGEOTag.Long : string.Empty,
                              (NSString)indexPath.Row.ToString()) {UserInteractionEnabled = true};
        }

        return cell;
    }

    public void AddDevice(FoundDeviceWithInfo device)
    {
        if (!Devices.Contains(device))
        {
            Devices.Add(device);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveDevice(FoundDeviceWithInfo device)
    {
        if (Devices.Contains(device))
        {
            Devices.Remove(device);
        }
    }

    public void ClearAllDevices()
    {
        Devices.Clear();
    }
}
```

Here is where I create my table view and assign it to my DeviceSource:

```
    _tableView = new UITableView
    {
        ScrollEnabled = true,
        Frame = new RectangleF(10, 74, View.Bounds.Width - 20, View.Bounds.Height - 84),
        AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All,
        Source = new DeviceSource(new List<FoundDeviceWithInfo>()),
        RowHeight = 45
    };

    ((DeviceSource)_tableView.Source).DeviceSelected += DeviceViewController_DeviceSelected;
```

Here is the method that is supposed to handle when the user selects an item in the list:

```
void DeviceViewController_DeviceSelected(object sender, ClientCommunication.AutoDiscovery.FoundDevice dev)
{
    UpnpController.GetInfo(dev);
}
```

The above method is NOT being called when I touch an item in my UITableView.  What am I missing here?  Am I misunderstanding the concept of 'Selected' in iOS?  I am totally new to iOS development and am using Xamarin so I can develop iOS apps using C#.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.  I'm sure that I'm just missing some really simple detail, but I can't figure out what it is..

Comment: can you verify (in debugger or using Console.Write) that the RowSelected is being fired?  Also, I don't believe you need to call base.RowSelected().

Comment: I put a breakpoint at the first line of code inside 'RowSelected' and it never gets called.

Comment: That's weird.  Does all of your other logic in DeviceSource work correctly?

Comment: if you comment out all of the event handler stuff, does the RowSelected fire?  Weird things can happen if you mix Delegates and Events, but I wouldn't expect that to happen in this case.

Comment: CORRECTION, when I removed base.RowSelected(..) Things still seemed broken.  So, then I added a Console.WriteLn().  Then things started working.  I took out the Console.WriteLn(), and things kept working.  Maybe it didn't rebuild or something the first time I took out base.RowSelected(..)..  Oh well, it's working now.  The solution was to not call the base class:  base.RowSelected(..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANK YOU JASON !!!

You nailed it.  I was calling the base class and I shouldn't:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    base.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath);

    if (DeviceSelected != null)
    {
        DeviceSelected(tableView, Devices[indexPath.Row].FoundDevice);
    }
}
```

Just needed to remove call to `base.RowSelected(..)`:

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (DeviceSelected != null)
    {
        DeviceSelected(tableView, Devices[indexPath.Row].FoundDevice);
    }
}
```

Now it works just fine.

Thanks JASON !!!